# Sharepoint for Teams, Permissions, Kick to proper tab?

Tags: security, sharepoint, permissions, server-message-block

I am working with a small non-profit that asked to have **Sharepoint Services 3** setup for them.  We have the system up and running, and created a few sites within the structure.  Right now we have:

- Home
- Finance
- Board
- Facilities
- Library

Right now we basically have 3 classes of users:

- Board Members (who should only have access to Board)
- Staff Members (who should ahve full access)
- Project Stakeholders (who should have access to Library)

Right now we have this configuration working, however if a board member goes to http://extranet.domain.com and logs in, they get a access denied page, but http://extranet.domain.com/board works.  The same for the stakeholders.

Do I need to migrate data out of the 'home' tab, and give everyone access to it so they can nagivate to these sub-tabs?  Is there not a way to simply 'kick' a user to their tabs they have access to?

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution is to investigate writing or buying a redirection webpart.  Bamboo seems to have one that would fit your bill.

You could also hack a CQWP to do the same thing in a less elegant but still works manner.

On your Kickoff page

1. Add a CQWP and put a redirect string in it.

   < meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://whever">
   *I had to put an extra space in this so the page could show it without redirecting*
2. Do that three times for each of your groups
3. Set the audience targeting to one group per webpart.  The Board would be targeted to the one that redirects to their pages and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I would migrate all data out of the root site and give everyone access to see that. Security trimming would cause them to only see the sub site(s) they have rights to. It is much cleaner (e.g. requires no customisation of SharePoint) and allows everyone to easily 'discover' what they can see.

Also, at some point you'll have a Board user who needs to see the Library site and how do you redirect to multiple tabs?